# How to web3 remote access to AWS private ethereum node

Tags: web3.py, aws

I am ETH newbie. Today I try setting up network by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5V2jdLi5mI&ab_channel=ChainSkills)

Then I start AWS EC2 for practicing purpose. I can use `geth` to do mining locally in single node. And I want to expand this service using web3 python.

This is my `startnode.sh` script that I bring up single node. It accepts all connection.

```bash
geth --networkid 112 --mine --miner.threads 1 --datadir '.' --nodiscover --http --http.port '8545' --port '30303' --http.corsdomain '*' --nat 'any' --http.api eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ~/private/password.txt --ipcpath '~/.ethereum/geth.ipc' --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Where I run `startnode.sh` here is the output

```bash
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.008] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.009] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.010] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.010] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.010] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/private/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=2048
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.028] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/ubuntu/private/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.029] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 112 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Berlin: <nil>, London: <nil>, Arrow Glacier: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.029] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/ubuntu/private/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.029] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethash             count=2
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.029] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=112 dbversion=8
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.033] Loaded most recent local header          number=362 hash=0a446a..a6f1e4 td=51,788,505 age=51s
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.033] Loaded most recent local full block      number=362 hash=0a446a..a6f1e4 td=51,788,505 age=51s
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.033] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=362 hash=0a446a..a6f1e4 td=51,788,505 age=51s
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.041] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.041] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.041] Switch sync mode from fast sync to full sync
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.042] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.043] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.12-stable-6c4dc6c3/linux-amd64/go1.17.2
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.060] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.060] New local node record                    seq=1,636,897,622,955 id=2725fd025ff19274 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=0 tcp=30303
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.060] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [11-14|14:37:54.061] Started P2P networking                   self="enode://7a11b92249b7f235d42e9b99cad76054f9e3fa42e68f13b4cfcb227f9118e4a761889cacd1d681b9a8bb070ee7fb3057b9d97f560458e75a15193f4b89c3b89a@127.0.0.1:30303?discport=0"
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.061] -------------------------------------------------------------------
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.061] Referring to accounts by order in the keystore folder is dangerous!
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.061] This functionality is deprecated and will be removed in the future!
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.061] Please use explicit addresses! (can search via `geth account list`)
WARN [11-14|14:37:54.061] -------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Unlocked account                         address=0x7a0678eDD4a088E2bF62bD858fc319bD5E47e0ba
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1,000,000,000
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1,000,000,000
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x7a0678eDD4a088E2bF62bD858fc319bD5E47e0ba
INFO [11-14|14:37:55.039] Commit new mining work                   number=363 sealhash=4afdec..ef043e uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="181.04µs"
```

My Inbound and bound policy is accept all traffic

**Problem:**
On my laptop. I want my Python software be able to connect to this node using web3

```py
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8545'))
w3.isConnected()
```

It always return false then I do remote access to it

**Question:**
How to use do web3 remote access to my server?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure if your request is really reaching your node. Run `tcpdump` in server side

```
sudo tcpdump -i any port 8545
```

If you can't see anything it means:

a. Nothing is leaving your local computer
b. AWS is blocking

In case a:

Check tcpdump in your computer, check firewalls, check if you can connect other computer in your same network, check if there are firewalls in your network.

In case b (a seems ok)

Check AWS settings.

Also check if you can change ports 8545 to other as 8000 or 8080, some providers block some unusual ports. Maybe 8000 or 8080 isn't blocked.